changing a 755 filesystem to 777 causing an error
chance@chanceOMEN:~$ chmod 777 "/media/chance/NEW NINTEND"

chmod: changing permissions of '/media/chance/NEW NINTEND': Read-only file system
im using ubuntu desktop, and the lock isn't going away, the drive is formatted in FAT32.

If you've mounted a drive/partition as read only, you cannot make any changes to it... you need to re-mount the partition/drive as read-write before you can make changes...  Do note if you mounted a partition as RW & it flips to RO, then a problem was detected, and the flipping from RW to RO is to prevent data loss, so explore logs as to what caused this flip & correct your problem...

ABOVE ANSWER/COMMENT is correct.  Could be in settings for storages you have it set to automount all new things as RO.  If so you can change that in settings. I have run into this before.  First of all I am not sure what is mounted(USB, partition etc).  Step 1 try sudo chmod instead of chmod. then I would take the directory and the files that are in it and make them owned by your user.  I am walt so I would sudo chown walt:walt -r /media/chance/'NEW NINTEND'

If the filesystem is FAT32 you will likely only be able to change mode via mount options - see for example How do I change permissions on a FAT32 formatted drive?
